# selenium popup box interaction

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having some difficulty interacting with a drag-able window that pops up.
After running the following code, a window shows up were I can do some customization. I am trying to click on the unselect all button that appears.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver.get("https://stats.oecd.org/Index.aspx?DataSetCode=HOUSE_PRICES#")
try:
    customize = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "customize-icon")))
    print("Customizing")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")
selection = driver.find_element_by_id("customize-menu-0")
menu = driver.find_element_by_id("customize-menu-3")
Hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(customize).move_to_element(selection).move_to_element(menu)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", menu)
```

I have tried the switch to alert and switch to popup functions, but I feel like the thing that shows up on this website isn't a pop up or an alert.

Any help to access and interact with the "popup" customization menu would greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

EDIT:
It seems that in the HTML, the popup table/window is called an iframe, and it has another html tag enclosing all of the content. The iframe is contained in a ui widget thing, and as a result I am unable to switch to the iframe directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesss, It works :)

Adding to the code I have above and referencing the iframe id directly:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("DialogFrame")
driver.find_element_by_id("lbtnClear_all").click()
```

I am able to access the "unselect all" item and click it.